# Converting TriRep to DelaunayTri while using pointLocation?

Tags: delaunay

I have a `TriRep` object with triangulations and I want to use `pointLocation` on the object to find whether the points are inside the triangles. But the `pointLocation` is a method defined for `DelaunayTri` class which is a subclass of `TriRep`.

So I would like to ask if `TriRep` object can be converted to `DelaunayTri` to be used in `pointLocation`?

Answer (score 1):

At my knowledge, there is no way to make such a conversion. While waiting a more elegant solution, I advice you using `tsearchn()` instead of `pointLocation()`. Best of all

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for the problem thanks to the Mathworks folks. It seems there is a way to typecast the TriRep object to be a delaunay triangulation. The details are given in this post - http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/bspqkfv-1.html#bspqkfv-4